# App installed from PlayStore displayed with inverted color

Tags: android

Application Tester is facing an issue with my Android App:

The App after installation from PlayStore displayed the whole UI with inverted colors.

His device has not that feature enabled in settings, all other apps on his device works pretty fine.

**PlayStore Country:** United States

**Device:** Samsung Galaxy S4

**What I tried:** creating US email Address by VPN and then using that email address in my device's PlayStore and then installed the application on my Samsung device. (I am facing issue about "invalid version of this application already on the device"). I tried clearing cache of device for playstore, but that too, is not working.

Let me know, if someone here has some suggestion for me about from where should I  start looking for the issue. Stick for last 2 days.

**Note:** Except for that particular device, the App works on all other devices. (Even on other Galaxy S4)

Thanks.